# How can I write data to a ini file on the fly

Tags: c#, windows, vbscript

In my office, the connection configuration parameters like userid password details are stored in a .ini file. Now since password cannot be stored as clear text, password comes from an external provider. I can write the password retrieval script in either vbscript or C#. But I would need to invoke this file for that action to be performed. I'm looking for an asynchronous solution wherein my script gets my password and writes to the ini file.

Comment: Is the .ini file on the network or on each machine?  Why does it need to be async?

Comment: This sounds like a seriously flawed security scheme.  If all you have to do to obtain a password is to login and runs a script then just skip the hassle of obtaining the password.  It doesn't make the system more secure.  It makes it *less* secure because an attacker can now crack that password.  Especially easy when you write it to a file.  Use the login credentials.  It is called "integrated security".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into [invoking delegates asynchronously](http://shiman.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/c-net-delegates-asynchronous-invocation-begininvoke-method/).

Comment: looks like the page was deleted that I linked to. ARGH!

Answer (score 1):

Writing the data is easy enough.  You could simply start a thread or backgroundworker and have it write the data to the file.